# Python dataframe to list of dictionaries grouped by column

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following table:

| Pattern | tag | Responses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hi | greeting | Hey :-) |
| hey | greeting | Hello, thanks for visiting |
| how are you | greeting | Hi there, what can I do for you? |
| Is anyone there? | greeting | Hi there, how can I help? |
| Bye | goodbye | See you later, thanks for visiting |
| See you later | goodbye | Have a nice day |
| Goodbye | goodbye | Bye! Come back again soon |

and I would like to group it by "tag" and obtain the following json format:

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "tag": "greeting",
      "patterns": [
        "Hi",
        "Hey",
        "How are you",
        "Is anyone there?"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Hey :-)",
        "Hello, thanks for visiting",
        "Hi there, what can I do for you?",
        "Hi there, how can I help?"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "goodbye",
      "patterns": ["Bye", "See you later", "Goodbye"],
      "responses": [
        "See you later, thanks for visiting",
        "Have a nice day",
        "Bye! Come back again soon"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried many things, e.g. the following:

```
df.groupby('tag').apply(lambda x: list(x['Pattern']))
```

but it is not exactly what I want... Does anybody have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this example how to format the dataframe your Json format:

```
import json

tmp = (
    df.groupby("tag")
    .apply(
        lambda x: dict(
            patterns=x["Pattern"].to_list(), responses=x["Responses"].to_list()
        )
    )
    .to_dict()
)

out = {"intents": []}
for k, v in tmp.items():
    out["intents"].append({})
    out["intents"][-1]["tag"] = k
    out["intents"][-1]["patterns"] = v["patterns"]
    out["intents"][-1]["responses"] = v["responses"]

print(json.dumps(out, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "intents": [
        {
            "tag": "goodbye",
            "patterns": [
                "Bye",
                "See you later",
                "Goodbye"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "See you later, thanks for visiting",
                "Have a nice day",
                "Bye! Come back again soon"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "greeting",
            "patterns": [
                "hi",
                "hey",
                "how are you",
                "Is anyone there?"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "Hey :-)",
                "Hello, thanks for visiting",
                "Hi there, what can I do for you?",
                "Hi there, how can I help?"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
def create_dic(x):
    
    d = {'tag': list(set(x['tag']))[0], 'patterns' : list(set(x['Pattern'])) , 'responses': list(set(x['Responses']))} 
    return d

result = {"intents"  : list( dict(df.groupby('tag').apply(lambda x: create_dic(x))).values()) }
```

Output:

```
print(result)
{'intents': [{'tag': 'goodbye',
   'patterns': ['Goodbye', 'Bye', 'See you later'],
   'responses': ['Bye! Come back again soon',
    'Have a nice day',
    'See you later, thanks for visiting']},
  {'tag': 'greeting',
   'patterns': ['Is anyone there?', 'how are you', 'hi', 'hey'],
   'responses': ['Hi there, how can I help?',
    'Hey :-)',
    'Hi there, what can I do for you?',
    'Hello, thanks for visiting']}]}
```